# Looking for a path to a simple plugin model

Tags: c#, plugins

I am building a plugin configuration application and I am looking for simple sample plugins approach in order to have clear idea where and how to go.

I have go through MEF description a bit but I think it is  a bit to heavy to what I am intend to do.

Any one have play around such approach and samples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF makes plugins *very* easy to implement. It has more features, but you don't *have* to use them. I recommend using it - it is not such a heavy library.

It is almost as simple as decorating the types with an attribute and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that these link will helps you for plugin model  using csharp...

- [pluginsincsharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pluginsincsharp.aspx)
- [csharp plugin_architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/c__plugin_architecture.aspx)
- [c sharp approach for a simple plugin service provider model
  different code dep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508772/c-sharp-approach-for-a-simple-plugin-service-provider-model-different-code-dep)